# CSS3 Hidden Span Transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to make the hidden span fade in when you hover over the image. I can't make it transition.

```
.thumb {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: -3px;
}

.thumb span {
display: none;
}

.thumb:hover span {
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding: 55px 0 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #ff6600;
opacity: .8;
width: 300px;
height: 95px;
font-size: 17px;
font-family: Candara;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
transition-property: opacity, background-color;
transition-duration: 25s ease-in;
}
```

Whats wrong with my css?

Answer (score 0):

".thumb:hover span" it says, your span tag has to be child to ".thumb" class tag. But you cant put "span into image tag'. Rather you can use jquery or else put ".thumb' class to the parent of span, so that the parent hover will trigger the effect you want. You can also have a common parent to both image and span.